# Activity log - Magento Community

Tags: admin, log

My problem is as follows:

I have one Magento community site, hosted on a virtual machine. I have two environments: PROD and DEV.

1,400 + products have been deleted from my PROD store.

My question is - are there activity logs that provide information (i.e. IP address of computer) that have actioned events from the Administration login?

I appreciate that there are some modules available that provide this information, but only going forward, not retrospectively.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magento 2 Opensource (Community) version, there is no default way to log admin user's activity.

Still there may be some clues:

1. The table **`admin_user_session`** keeps the session information about all the admin users (if not truncated/deleted/modified manually).
2. You can check server's **`access.log`** to know the requests sent to your web server using a browser.

It may not get back your precious data, but it may help you to find the culprit.

Once you recover/ignore your data, you can install a custom extension to track the activity.

Also, change **server login access**, **Magento admin panel access**, **mySQL login details** as soon as possible and never share it with anyone you don't trust.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have investigated the admin_user_access table. There is an entry in user_id column marked as NULL which immediately precedes the mass deletion (I think). There are only two other user_ID's: 1 & 2. Could this mean an account has been created and then deleted retrospectively?

Comment: It may be possible.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply - this is what I suspected.  I assume this would be difficult to verify?

Answer (score 0):

Admin action logs have always been a pain for us in M1 and now in M2. We are not sure why Magento 2 doesn't add this feature in the product itself.

Anyways we installed the following module on our website and it works great for logging all admin activities. It also gives us information about the old and new data which is very useful in case we want to revert the changes back to original -:

[Magento 2 Admin Activity Action Log](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-admin-activity-log.html)